# Does Ethereum use the longest chain rule like bitcoin?

Tags: uncle-blocks, blockchain-fork, ghost-protocol

I can't seem to find a straight answer to this question. I know that Uncles are rewarded, but are they used to help secure the network? Or does Ethereum use the longest chain rule like Bitcoin?

Comment: Hey Lauri, thanks for the comment, the answers were kind of conflicting on that post, but i found a clear answer when I took a look at the EIPs on GitHub.

Answer (score 0):

Update: After EIP 100, uncles are included in calculating the target difficulty, meaning they are a factor in determining the overall PoW on a chain.